# Filter FeatureCollection by geometry type in GEE python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

[image]I have a featurecollection with 141 objects inside (135 polygon, 4 geometrycollection and 2 multipolygon) an I have problems to indicate in a loop the region for images exportation in GEE, so I need to filter in the collection only the objects of polygon type for example for run the code easily.

```
table= ee.FeatureCollection("users/tpc/capas")
lista = table.toList(table.size())
m= lista.getInfo()

for i in range(0,141):

    predio_id = ee.Feature(lista.get(i)).getInfo()["properties"]["id"]
    predio = ee.Feature(lista.get(i)).geometry()
    predio_region= predio.getInfo()["coordinates"]

    S2_NDVI_Col= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterBounds(predio).filterDate(dateNDVI,today).filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30)).map(addNDVI).map(addSAVI).map(addNDMI).map(addEVI)
    S2_NDVI = S2_NDVI_Col.sort("system:time_start")

    n_img=4000
    colListNDVI = S2_NDVI.toList(n_img)
    n= colListNDVI.size().getInfo()

    for j in range(0,n):
        NDVI = ee.Image(colListNDVI.get(j)) #obtiene la imagen n
        id_NDVI = NDVI.id().getInfo()
        x1 = len(id_NDVI)
        dateNDVI = id_NDVI[x1-38:8].replace('_','')
        int_dateNDVI = int(dateNDVI[5:7])
        print(dateNDVI)
        export = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(\
                                               image=NDVI.select("NDVI").float(),
                                               description='S2_NDVI_'+predio_id+"_"+dateNDVI,
                                               maxPixels= 220582361000,
                                               region=predio_region,
                                               folder='S2_FNDR_NDVI',
                                               scale = 10,
                                               crs='EPSG:4326')#,
        export.start()
    print('Descarga MODIS finalizada')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share your collection.

You can map over your collection, adding the geometry type, then filter on it.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc3bc26ebda415d48bdfee6df3f1577d

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('geometryType', feature.geometry().type())
  })
  .filterMetadata('geometryType', 'equals', 'Polygon')
print(table.first())
```